# AWS SQS and DocuSign Connect - "Queue receive error: The security token included in the request is invalid."

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, docusignapi, amazon-sqs

I am attempting to connect AWS SQS with DocuSign Connect using this DocuSign Connect Worker for AWS.

https://github.com/docusign/connect-csharp-worker-aws

I followed the repo's [README.md](https://github.com/docusign/connect-csharp-worker-aws/blob/master/README.md) step-by-step, set up AWS Lambda and API Gateway, received a successful response from Lambda. However, when I run the worker, I received this error message:

```
3/19/2021 12:42:17 AM Starting queue worker
3/19/2021 12:42:17 AM Awaiting a message...
3/19/2021 12:42:18 AM Queue receive error:
The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I am suspecting that the part where I got wrong would be the App.config file below. Due to security reason, I am not sharing the values in the config file. But what should be the AWS_ACCOUNT and AWS_SECRET values (is it the AWS root account ID number and its root secret key or just an IAM user name and its secret key?) and why are they appearing twice in the code? Is it because they have to be provided twice following the JWT OAuth authentication flow? Is there a step missing in the README to add the DocuSign keypair's public key to an AWS IAM user or at an account level?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Your data -->
    <add key="DS_CLIENT_ID" value="{DS_CLIENT_ID}" />
    <add key="DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID" value="{DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUI}" />
    <add key="AWS_ACCOUNT" value="{AWS_ACCOUNT}" />
    <add key="AWS_SECRET" value="{AWS_SECRET}" />
    <add key="BASIC_AUTH_NAME" value="{BASIC_AUTH_NAME}" />
    <add key="BASIC_AUTH_PW" value="{BASIC_AUTH_PW}" />
    <add key="QUEUE_URL" value="{QUEUE_URL}" />
    <add key="AWS_ACCOUNT" value="{AWS_ACCOUNT}" />
    <add key="AWS_SECRET" value="{AWS_SECRET}" />
    <add key="DS_PRIVATE_KEY" value="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xA;
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xA;
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xA;
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXR8q+ReuJAoIBA/omKBC10Fi8ez&#xA;
...
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAAshxKUsvW7Kf8a60BoVMi32qyGrK&#xA;
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;" />
    <!-- Used for testing -->
    <add key="DS_CC_1_EMAIL" value="{DS_CC_1_EMAIL}" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_NAME" value="{DS_CC_1_NAME}" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_EMAIL" value="{DS_SIGNER_1_EMAIL}" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_NAME" value="{DS_SIGNER_1_NAME}" />
    <add key="ENABLE_BREAK_TEST" value="true" />
    <add key="TEST_OUTPUT_DIR_NAME" value="test_messages" />
    <add key="ENQUEUE_URL" value="{ENQUEUE_URL}" />
    <!-- Default data -->
    <add key="DS_TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID" value="FALSE" />
    <add key="DS_AUTH_SERVER" value="https://account-d.docusign.com"/>
    <add key="DEBUG" value="true" />
    <add key="ENVELOPE_CUSTOM_FIELD" value="Sales order" />
    <add key="OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX" value="order_" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the following sample app I think it might help: https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-worker-aws

Reading the readme.md you'll see the following in steps 2 & 3:

2. Using AWS IAM, create an IAM User with access to your SQS queue. Record the IAM user's AWS Access Key and Secret.
3. Configure environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY with the IAM user credentials.

You can find the complementary listener code to this worker example here: https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws

Comment: Thank you robkni! I put the access key id for the AWS_ACCOUNT value and the secret key for the AWS_SECRET value for an IAM user that has permission to the AWS SQS and it worked!